# How to install perception_oru package from github?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to install perception_oru package from github. But I had faced problem while approaching the following steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tstoyanov/perception_oru-release.git
$ cd perception_oru-release
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

Then the following error appears.

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/baban/perception_oru-release" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

I need to know if there is any cmakelists.txt for this package or how to install this package. This is the prerequisite to create NDT map using NDTfuser.

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226483/how-to-install-perception_oru-package-from-github?/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-03-18**:
try to clone it to your workspace directory that is source on your `.\bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The master branch does not contain any code. Try:

```
git checkout release-source
```

Also, use `catkin_make` or `catkin build` instead of cmake directly, if you are using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) with karma: 111 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0